# Why my jQuery not working when page loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which works fine only if input changes.
I want my script start working when the page loaded and then when input will change.
What is wrong with my script?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pricevat = <?php echo $vat; ?>;
  $('input[name=quantity]').on( 'input change', function(){
    var productQty   =  parseFloat($(".to_overlock").val());
    var meter =  parseFloat($(".qty").val());
    overlock = (((meter + productQty) *2) * pricevat).toFixed(2);
    $('#price_overlock').val(overlock);
  });
})

function my_val() {
  var singleValues = $('#pa_shirina-rulona').val();
  var stringNum = parseInt( singleValues );
  $('#to_overlock').val(stringNum);
}

$('select').change(my_val);
my_val();

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=quantity]').on( 'input change', function(){
    var meters   =  parseFloat($(".to_overlock").val());
    var qty =  parseFloat($(".qty").val());
    square = ((meters * qty)).toFixed(2);
    $('#square').val(square);
  });
})

</script>
```

Comment: I need to do with this string `$('input[name=quantity]').on( 'input change', function(){` 
All my script works only when input quantity change. But not works when page loaded. I mean all my values are showing only when you click on input quantity

Answer (score 0):

Try with this quicly cleaned code.

You had two event handlers for the same selector and same events... I merged them.

And one `$(document).ready()` is enought to wrap everything.

The call to `$('select').change(my_val);` was not inside the ready handler... So maybe that was the issue...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pricevat = <?php echo $vat; ?>;
  
  $('input[name=quantity]').on( 'input change', function(){
    var productQty =  parseFloat($(".to_overlock").val());
    var meters = parseFloat($(".qty").val());
    var qty = parseFloat($(".qty").val());
    
    var overlock = (((meters + productQty) *2) * pricevat).toFixed(2);
    $('#price_overlock').val(overlock);

    var square = ((meters * qty)).toFixed(2);
    $('#square').val(square);
  });

  function my_val() {
    var singleValues = $('#pa_shirina-rulona').val();
    var stringNum = parseInt( singleValues );
    $('#to_overlock').val(stringNum);
  }

  $('select').change(my_val);
  my_val();

});

</script>
```

Comment: I need to do with this string `$('input[name=quantity]').on( 'input change', function(){` 
All my script works only when input quantity change. But not works when page loaded. I mean all my values are showing only when you click on input quantity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I made triger for my page content id.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var pricevat = <?php echo $vat; ?>;
      $('#variator').on( 'change', function(e){
        var productQty   =  parseFloat($(".to_overlock").val());
        var meter =  parseFloat($(".qty").val());
        overlock = (((meter + productQty) *2) * pricevat).toFixed(2);
        $('#price_overlock').val(overlock);
    
        var meters   =  parseFloat($(".to_overlock").val());
        var qty =  parseFloat($(".qty").val());
        square = ((meters * qty)).toFixed(2);
        $('#square').val(square);
      });}) 
        
    function my_val() {
      var singleValues = $('#pa_shirina-rulona').val();
      var stringNum = parseInt( singleValues );
      $('#to_overlock').val(stringNum);
    }
    
    $('select').change(my_val);
    my_val();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can trigger a change event on page load after you have initialized the event listener(s)

```js
const $sel = $('select').on('change', function(){
    $('input').val(this.value);
    console.log('change triggered')
})


$sel.val('2').change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input/>
```